# How do I merge two dictionaries in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
var a = {};
a['fruit'] = "apple";

var b = {};
b['vegetable'] = "carrot";

var food = {};
```

The output variable 'food' must include both key-value pairs.

Comment: try `var food = Object.assign({}, a, b)`

Answer (score 104):

You could use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

```js
var a = { fruit: "apple" },
    b = { vegetable: "carrot" },
    food = Object.assign({}, a, b);

console.log(food);
```

For browser without supporting `Object.assign`, you could iterate the properties and assign the values manually.

```js
var a = { fruit: "apple" },
    b = { vegetable: "carrot" },
    food = [a, b].reduce(function (r, o) {
        Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) { r[k] = o[k]; });
        return r;
    }, {});

console.log(food);
```

Answer (score 99):

**Ways to achieve :**

**1.** Using JavaScript [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) method.

```js
var a = {};
a['fruit'] = "apple";

var b = {};
b['vegetable'] = "carrot";

var food = Object.assign({}, a, b);

console.log(food);
```

**2.** Using custom function.

```js
var a = {};
a['fruit'] = "apple";

var b = {};
b['vegetable'] = "carrot";

function createObj(obj1, obj2){
    var food = {};
    for (var i in obj1) {
      food[i] = obj1[i];
    }
    for (var j in obj2) {
      food[j] = obj2[j];
    }
    return food;
};

var res = createObj(a, b);

console.log(res);
```

**3.** Using ES6 [Spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator).

```js
let a = {};
a['fruit'] = "apple";

let b = {};
b['vegetable'] = "carrot";

let food = {...a,...b}

console.log(food)
```

Comment: seems 3 is the standard js way now https://stackoverflow.com/a/171256/3705490

Answer (score 27):

You could use the spread operator in es6, but you would need to use babel to transpile the code to be cross browser friendly.

```js
const a = {};
a['fruit'] = "apple";

const b = {};
b['vegetable'] = "carrot";

const food = { ...a, ...b }

console.log(food)
```

Comment: Available only in es6. on es5 it would show lint error.

Answer (score 1):

Create a *Utility function* which can extend Objects, like:

```
function extendObj(obj1, obj2){
    for (var key in obj2){
        if(obj2.hasOwnProperty(key)){
            obj1[key] = obj2[key];
        }
    }

    return obj1;
}
```

And then extend this `food` object with the another Objects. Here is example:

```
food = extendObj(food, a);
food = extendObj(food, b);
```